# Community Builder usage of jQuery (or any external .js resource)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, community-builder

I'm trying to use jQuery from one of my component helpers inside Community Builder (Lightning Component). I'm concerned about reference conflicts across the various components that may be used, so I don't want to use a static resource reference within the component, itself.

I found [this recommendation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_commbuilder_jquery.htm) to be that you include the script reference in the  section for the entire community (which would be a great solution, in my case).

I tried adding the script reference in this section for my community, but it didn't work. I'm using Winter 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ltng:require to make sure your jquery is encapsulated in every component .Loading the external script on the head might not be available inside each of the component while ltng:require ensures you have files completed loaded

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.***resourceName***}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

Note the Jquery has to be inside the static resources .

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm concerned about reference/version conflicts. What are the precautions that should be taken to mitigate these risks? The conversation about loading external .js resources in the community seem to be divided. [https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_commbuilder_jquery.htm](This recommendation) that I mentioned is in the release notes from the development team.